# Window function to calculate average in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, average, partitioning

I don’t have much experience with window functions and I have to use one for my average calculation,
This is my code:

```
    AVG(b.TotalSilkHrs) OVER(partition BY b.TECHNICIANCODE
    ORDER BY b.rankID 
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW and 3 FOLLOWING) AS MovingAvg
```

I calculate average of sum that was calculated in subquery.
It gives me error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
>   Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'.

Why am I getting error? I used the code I got from your site

Comment: I don't think SQL Server supports this type of the partition definition. If at all, you would need SQL Server 2012, before that implementation of Window functions was very limited.

Comment: which version of `SQL Server` are you using?

Comment: That [OVER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause is supported from SQL Server 2012.

Comment: 2008 R2. How else I can calculate avg limited by period on subquery?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Window functions were introduced in SQL Server 2005 but that did not support running aggregates by including an  `order by` in the window definition. That was introduced in SQL Server 2012, but I'm still not sure if the `rows between ...` option is suported in 2012

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I probably should have emphasized. "**That** `over()` clause ...."

Answer (score 1):

Your original syntax works only for SQL Server 2012, for older versions Try this

```
;WITH AVGCTE AS
(
     SELECT *, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY TECHNICIANCODE ORDER BY rankID) Rn 
     FROM TableA
)

SELECT A.*, B.AVG_COL
FROM AVGCTE A
CROSS APPLY 
(
   SELECT x.AVG(TotalSilkHrs) AVG_COL 
   FROM AVGCTE x WHERE x.Rn BETWEEN A.rn and a.rn + 2  
   AND  A.TECHNICIANCODE  = x.TECHNICIANCODE        
) B
```

Comment: The first statement doesn’t work because I have to limit the period The second code doesn’t work too because my sum is calculated from only 5 different tables and when I line them up in this sub select statement, it doesnt work for either.

Comment: @user2019324, post all your tables and sample data, in your question you did not mention even a single table name and you expect us to answer when information is missing from the question? I gave you sample query that answers your question above, use that and update that to make it work with your original query